# Почему не работает код: List<Object> list = (List<Object>) List<MyOwnObject>();

Tags: java, коллекции

Нужно сделать такой даункастинг:

```
List<Object> list = (List<Object>) List<MyOwnObject>();
```

Почему не получается?

Мне нужно создать метод который будет принимать лист **любых** объектов и сохранять их содержимое (через `toString`) в файл.

Comment: Что значит "не получается"? Приведите текст ошибки

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я правильно понял: вопрос про наследование в дженерик классах?
Если да, то в вашем случае код должен выглядеть так:

```
List<? extends Object> list = new ArrayList<MyOwnObject>();
```

Поскольку это `Object` то можно просто

```
List<?> list = new ArrayList<MyOwnObject>();
```

Answer (score 5):

[List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) это интерфейс, нельзя создавать объекты от него.

Объекты можно будет создать от классов (или их потомков), которые реализуют этот интерфейс, такие как: [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), [Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html), [Vector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)

Кроме того, в примере вопроса нет самого создания объекта, нет оператора `new`

Правильно будет:

```
List list = new ArrayList<MyOwnObject>();

// Еще вариант:
List<Object> list = (java.util.List) new ArrayList<MyOwnObject>();
```

Контейнер без типа (такой как `List list`) считается контейнером `Object`. Т.е. `List list` для java это `List<Object> list`